# Redirect all Virtual Host naked domains to the www site

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, redirect

My apache server has numerous `VirtualHosts` and I'd like to have **one** rule that would redirect the naked domain for all of them to the `www` domain. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the other answer, I was able to get it to work by creating a catch-all `VirtualHost` at the bottom of the file that redirect a request to a named `www` host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default
  ServerAlias *
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # WITH 'www.'
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.(.*) [nocase]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [redirect=permanent,nocase,last]
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Only one VirtualHost section matches each request, so not sure how you can have this, and other VirtualHosts... Unless you don't have multiple VirtualHosts.

Comment: I think it works like this: the naked domain request matches this catch-all vhost and gets rewritten as a www.* request which matches a named vhost. http://jamiekrug.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/8/6/catch-all-apache-virtual-host-to-force-www-redirect-on-canonical-hostnames

Comment: I was also inspired by this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3213665/1218575

Comment: I see, clever! I like it :)
What happens when fake.com gets redirected to www.fake.com that doesn't have a specific named host, so matches the catch-all vhost again? You'll need to 403 that or something...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.(.*) [nocase]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [redirect=permanent,nocase,last]
```

1. The `RewriteCond` matches any HTTP_HOST that does NOT start with `www.`
2. The `RewriteRule` prepends `www.` to the back-reference to `RewriteCond` (%1) then appends whatever the actual request was with the back-reference to the `RewriteRule` match string

Comment: Note that this could have the undesired side effect of redirecting non-www subdomains like `login.example.com` to potentially nonexistent www subdomains like `www.login.example.com`.

Comment: @MilesErickson is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Also these rules just go at the bottom of the `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: Good point @MilesErickson I didn't think of that. If they're all .com domains then you could modify the RewriteCond to have a more specific regex such as `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.(.*\.com)$ [nocase]` And yes, that goes in the httpd.conf (or an included config file such as `/etc/httpd/cond.d/*.conf` on RedHat based systems)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear on where these rules go. I put them at the bottom of the file and it looks like it's not working. Should they go inside a `<VirtualHost>` section?

Comment: @sguha You would have to duplicate it for every VirtualHost if you did that. Make sure you have `RewriteEngine On` before those lines in httpd.conf and there's no other RewriteRules that are coming first with a `last` directive. RewriteLog (check the Apache docs) can assist you to debug it.